# How to force a certain wideness to website on mobile with css/html

Tags: mobile, web, viewport, scaling, meta

I created a website from a template (HTML/CSS) and I mostly tested it from my computer in chrome/firefox/IE but now I just tested the page on my iPhone and it looks wrong.

link: www.anibalautomotive.com

I tested a bit with the viewport meta and it helped but didn't correct some of the issues. I tried putting ''max-width:1200px'' in the body, it actually worked pretty well but the backgrounds were all zoomed in.

What could be a good route to adapt the website to mobiles while keeping it clean?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), It uses a responsive grid amongst other things to allow you to design layout changes based on screen width.

For a lighter-weight version i'm sure you can find one with a googe search for 'responsive grid'.

Alternatively to just affect a small portion of code you could always just write in your CSS

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
/* Enter CSS code here as normal */
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:979px) {
 /* Enter CSS code here as normal */
}
@media (min-width: 980px) {
 /* Enter CSS code here as normal */
}
```

Those are example sizes of phone, tablet and desktop although some just do 2. Heres what the code looks like with CSS inside so you get an idea:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
body {
    font-size:18px;
}
.myClass {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Scargi. I looked into my template and it seems to be using Boostrap... and I also looked for some of the @Media tags, that I cleaned it up a bit.

It's almost ok now, but I can't seem to make the site more than 1000px wide on mobiles.

Basically, I would need it to show a bit more space around the content  (about 1000px wide) in the middle.

Any ideas?

link: http://www.anibalautomotive.com

Comment: Hi Thomas, I didn't realise you shared a link before so apologies on that. Sadly you can't grant websites to use more px, it decides that i'm afraid.
After looking around your website a bit i jump back to the media tags thought, it's usually a great way to apply style to mobile and not desktop which is very useful for tweaking/finalising .